# Combo item displayed over form using ReportViewer

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm working in a very old implementation we had using a ReportViewer control that has a custom implementation for Export event.
Basically inside of this event a save dialog is displayed but the selected item in the combo remains on the save dialog form.

Has this control any property for this ? I tried using many of them, none of them work. :(

```
Private Sub ReportViewer_ReportExport(sender As Object, e As ReportExportEventArgs) Handles ReportViewerData.ReportExport
    e.Cancel = True
    Dim fileNameExtension As String = e.Extension.Name
    Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()

    If fileNameExtension.Equals("Excel") Then
        saveDialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
        saveDialog.DefaultExt = "xlsx"
    ElseIf fileNameExtension.Equals("PDF") Then
        saveDialog.Filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
        saveDialog.DefaultExt = "pdf"
    ElseIf fileNameExtension.Equals("WORD") Then
        saveDialog.Filter = "Word Documents (*.doc)|*.doc"
        saveDialog.DefaultExt = "docx"
    End If

    saveDialog.FileName = "Report"
    saveDialog.AddExtension = True

    If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ''Doing something here whatever, here combo item remains on the form
        '
    End If

End Sub
```

Is there any workaround for this ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try using Me.BeginInvoke() so the dialog runs later, after the event is handled.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! :)